# How do I toggle hide/show between three divs; using three buttons (each belongs to one div) dynamically?

Tags: javascript, dom, button, toggle

lets say, I have

```
<div class = "buttons">
<button onclick= "toggleFirst()"> Show me Hide me 1</button>
<button onclick= "toggleSecond()"> Show me Hide me 2</button>
<button onclick= "toggleThird();"> Show me Hide me 3</button>
</div>

<div style="display: none"  id="one" >  Random Content1 < /div>
   <div style="display: none"  id="two" >  Random Content 2< /div>
       <div style="display: none"  id="three" >  Random Content 3< /div>
```

How can I write a JavaScript function or functions (no jquery please) that will toggle on and off content dynamically based on each button? if i click button 1, I want  content in div id one to show, if i click it again, I want content in div id one to hide and or when i click button 2 , I want only content in dive id two to show and hide other stuff...so same patter and logic for all of them.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Comment: had this and not working quite.
function toggleFirst(){
  var x = document.getElementById("one");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
function toggleSecond(){
  var y = document.getElementById("two");
  if (y.style.display === "none") {
    y.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    y.style.display = "none";
  }
}
function toggleThird(){
  var z = document.getElementById("three");
  if (z.style.display === "none") {
    z.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    z.style.display = "none";
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

You've already started by giving each of those buttons a function to execute onClick. Just define those functions and check the display property of the style property of your divs.

I went ahead and made a simpler `toggleId` function as well to limit how much code is duplicated.

It's also worth noting that `< /div>` is invalid. You don't put a space in the front of a closing HTML tag. You can put one at the end, but there's no reason to. Just use `</div>`.

```js
function toggleFirst()
{
  toggleId("one"); 
}

function toggleSecond()
{
  toggleId("two");
}

function toggleThird()
{
  toggleId("three");
}

function toggleId(id)
{
  var div = document.getElementById(id);
  if(div.style.display == "none")
    div.style.display = "block";
  else
    div.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class = "buttons">
<button onclick= "toggleFirst()"> Show me Hide me 1</button>
<button onclick= "toggleSecond()"> Show me Hide me 2</button>
<button onclick= "toggleThird();"> Show me Hide me 3</button>
</div>

<div style="display: none"  id="one" >  Random Content1 </div>
<div style="display: none"  id="two" >  Random Content 2</div>
<div style="display: none"  id="three" >  Random Content 3</div>
```

Comment: thank you I had written something similar but, in addition to this, how can i hide the previous div, if decide to like go from button two to button three and i didn't toggle off the previous content? if that makes sense?

Comment: You can select them all with `document.getElementById("id")` calls and set their displays to none just like the other one or use `document.querySelectorAll("selector")`

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use the `style.display` property

```js
function toggleFirst() {
  let one = document.getElementById("one");
  if (one.style.display == "none") {
    one.style.display = "block"
  } else {
    one.style.display = "none"
  }
}

function toggleSecond() {
  let two = document.getElementById("two");
  if (two.style.display == "none") {
    two.style.display = "block"
  } else {
    two.style.display = "none"
  }
}

function toggleThird() {
  let three = document.getElementById("three");
  if (three.style.display == "none") {
    three.style.display = "block"
  } else {
    three.style.display = "none"
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button onclick="toggleFirst()"> Show me Hide me 1</button>
  <button onclick="toggleSecond()"> Show me Hide me 2</button>
  <button onclick="toggleThird();"> Show me Hide me 3</button>
</div>

<div style="display: none" id="one"> Random Content1
</div>
<div style="display: none" id="two"> Random Content 2
</div>
<div style="display: none" id="three"> Random Content 3
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the functions onclick like i did  and you don't have to do 3 functions
, you just need one

```js
 function toggContent(content_id) {
            const x = document.getElementById(content_id)
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
        <button onclick="toggContent('one')"> Show me Hide me 1</button>
        <button onclick="toggContent('two')"> Show me Hide me 2</button>
        <button onclick="toggContent('three')"> Show me Hide me 1</button>
    </div>

    <div style="display: none" id="one"> Random Content1
    </div>
    <div style="display: none" id="two"> Random Content 2
    </div>
    <div style="display: none" id="three"> Random Content 3
    </div>
```